# Trouble with detail in proof of Weierstraß theorem

Tags: continuity, proof-explanation

I'm finding myself in hard times trying to understand why is this an absurdity. Here is the demonstration from my book:

**Statement**: Let $f: [a,b] → ℝ$ be a continuous function on all his domain, then it allows a maximum and a minimum in $[a,b]$.

**Formally**: $f: [a,b] → ℝ, f ∈ C⁰( [a,b] ) ⇒ ∃ (m, M) ∈ [a,b] | ∀ x ∈ [a,b] f(m) ≼ f(x) ≼ f(M)$

**Proof**: We want to show that, being $f: [a,b] → ℝ, f ∈ C⁰( [a,b] )$, the function f allows a minimum. Being f a continuous function, due to the Bolzano's theorem, its image is a new interval, defined as $[ inf( f([a,b]) ), sup( f([a,b]) ) ]$. Formally we want to show that $∃x₀∈[a,b] | ∀x ∈ [a,b], f(x) ≽ f(x₀)$. We still can't say if this is or not $-∞$, so without going specific, we can set $L = inf ( f([a,b]) )$.

We can therefore select a point on the ordinate, let's call it $t > L$ and define the set $E(t):= { x ∈ [a,b] | f(x) < t }$, which will contain all the points in the domain of the function which image is within $(L, t)$. Again we can do the same thing with a new point on the ordinate, let's call it s, with $s > t$, and define again the new set $E(s):= {x ∈ [a,b] | f(x) < s}$. First of all, being $E(t)$ defined as union of non-empty intervals, it's a non-empty set. Moreover you have that all the elements of $E(t)$ are within $E(s)$, i.e. $E(t) ⊂ E(s)$. Let's now define the function $x(t):= inf( E(t) )$ on varying of t on the ordinates. The function x is defined only for arguments such that $t > L$. Additionally, being $s > t$ you have that $x(s) ≼ x(t)$, the $x(t)$ function is monotonically decreasing. For the theorem of existence of the limit for monotonic functions, you have that ∃ $\lim_{t \to L^+} x(t)$, and its value equals $sup( x(t) )$. The function $f$, for hypothesis, is limited, and so, being $x₀= \lim_{t \to L^+} x(t)$, you have that $x₀ ∈ ℝ$. Being $L = inf( f([a,b]) )$, $f(x₀)$ needs to be $≽ L$. We will suppose that $f(x₀) > L$ and show that it will lead to an absurdity, so we'll have to assert that $f(x₀) = L$.

You have 3 different chances: $x₀ = a$, $x₀ = b$, or $x₀∈(a,b)$.
We select the third chance and suppose that $f(x₀) > L$. Being f a continuous function, $\lim_{x \to x₀} f(x) = f(x₀) > L$. [**At this point I don't get why, but it still isn't the question**] So, for the sign permanence theorem we have that $∃(M, δ) ∈ ℝ+ | ∀ x ∈ ( x₀-δ, x₀+δ )∩[a,b] , f(x) > M$. For each choice of $t$ in $(L,M]$, you have that $t < M$ while $f(x) > M$ when $x ∈ ( x₀-δ, x₀+δ )∩[a,b]$, so $f(x) > t$. This means that $E(t)$ can contain no point of $( x₀-δ, x₀+δ )∩[a,b]$. This means that $x(t) ≼ x₀-δ ⋎ x(t) ≽ x₀+δ$.
$x(t) ≽ x₀+δ$ is obviously absurd, because x₀ is supposed to be the $sup$ for $x(t)$ and no element of $x(t)$ may be bigger than the $sup$, so you must have that $x(t) ≼ x₀-δ$, and this is an absurdity too, due to the fact that $x(t)$ is a monotonically decreasing function. We shall assert that $f(x₀) = L = inf( f([a,b]) )$.

[I needed to translate all, so I'm sorry for errors, if any]

This last part is what I don't get: why is it absurd that $x(t) ≼ x₀-δ$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'll do my best to add it now, but I've never used and I don't know how it works so I don't promise.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I did it, I think this way should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have that $x_0$ is the limit as $t$ tends to $L$ from above of $x(t)$.

If $x(t)$ is monotonically decreasing, to suggest that $x_0 - \delta > x(t)$ is absurd because $t > L$, as $t \in (L,M]$.

Comment: I'm quite not getting it: we have that $x0=sup (x(t))$, then $sup(x(t))-δ>x(t)$ why is absurd?

Answer (score 0):

I went to this conclusion: If  $x(t) < x₀−δ$ you have that the definition must be valid for each $t$ argument, so it must be satisfied even for $sup(x(t)) = x₀$. Therefore you have that $x₀ < x₀−δ$ which is absurd.